# disable div using radio button

Tags: javascript, html

i want to disable my some of my div using radio button, the radio button should be disable and enable the div accoring to the radion button. i want it still showing but you can't make any input or change to the inputbox

here is the code of the div

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left"> Apakah Penerima KPS / PKH
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 radio text-left">
      <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Ya" class="radio_penerima_kps" name="radio_penerima_kps" id="penerima_kps_ya">
          Ya
      </label>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Tidak" class="radio_penerima_kps" name="radio_penerima_kps" id="penerima_kps_tidak" >
          Tidak
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form_kps">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left">No. KPS / PKH
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" id="nomor_kps_pkh" name="nomor_kps_pkh" value="<?=@$registration->nomor_kps_pkh?>"  onchange="update_data()">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Usulan dari sekolah layak PIP
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" id="usulan_sekolah_layak_pip" name="usulan_sekolah_layak_pip" value="<?=@$registration->usulan_sekolah_layak_pip?>"  onchange="update_data()">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Alasan Layak
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" id="alasan_layak" name="alasan_layak" value="<?=@$registration->alasan_layak?>"  onchange="update_data()">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the code of javascript that i'm using.

```
$(".radio_penerima_kps").click(function () {
    if($(this).val() == "Ya"){
       $("#nomor_kps_pkh").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#usulan_sekolah_layak_pip").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#alasan_layak").prop("disabled", false);
    }else{
      $("#nomor_kps_pkh").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#usulan_sekolah_layak_pip").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#alasan_layak").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: do you want disable a div or the form, sorry ?

Comment: my bad, the div

Comment: What do you mean "disable the div"? Hide it? Div is not something you can disable...

Comment: maybe readonly, i just want to show but can't edit it

Comment: where can you edit a div in your example? I don't understand what you want...

Comment: you can't type the input , so disable input like `<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" id="nomor_kps_pkh" name="nomor_kps_pkh" value="<?=@$registration->nomor_kps_pkh?>"  onchange="update_data()">` according the radiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

in case condition fail, change div style. divs can not be enable or disable, only inputs

```
 $("#form_kps").css('background', "#ccc")
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
so there is no way i can change all the input that contained in that div ?

Comment: changes it, and how to ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input associated with the div by using:

```
$(".radio_penerima_kps").click(function () {
if($(this).val() == "Ya"){
    $('#form_kps .form-control').prop("disabled", false);

}else{
  $('#form_kps .form-control').prop("disabled", true);

}
```

});

So, you basically use the id of the div and the class associated with it to change the values of the input. There is no way to enable/disable divs.